# How can I program music from an app to play on a specific time?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I want to create an app that lets me go to the iOS music app, like a sub view controller but I'm not sure how I can do that. Can any of you tell me what I can do? I also want to learn how to trigger a playlist on a specific time.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot present the iOS Music app within another app in iOS.  You'll need to review [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765) and build the functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read the documentation and tutorials of Apple ?

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/audio-and-video.html

You can read the iPod Library